# sfdc select result in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I insert the output of query_result in pandas dataframe? The query result first gets 500 records and using QueryMore the remaining records are pulled. I am unable to push everything in df along with column names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import beatbox
import sqlalchemy

engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://db-user:db-pass@localhost/db-name'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
connection = engine.connect()

sf = beatbox._tPartnerNS
service = beatbox.Client()
def sync_user(objectSOQL):
    service.login('sfdc-username', 'sfdc-creds')
    query_result = service.query(objectSOQL)
    while True:
        for row in query_result[sf.records:]:
            SQL_query = 'INSERT INTO user(' \
                        'id, ' \
                        'name, ' \
                        'department, ' \
                        'sales_team) ' \
                        'VALUES(' \
                        '\"{}\",\"{}\",\"{}\",\"{}\"' \
                        ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '\
                        'name = VALUES(name), '\
                        'department = VALUES(department), '\
                        'sales_team = VALUES(sales_team) '\
                        .format(
                        row[2],
                        row[3],
                        row[4],
                        row[5]
                        )
            # SQL_query = SQL_query.replace('\"None\"', 'NULL')

            try:
                connection.execute(SQL_query)
            except Exception as e:
                print(id, e)

        if str(query_result[sf.done]) == 'true':
            break
        query_result = service.queryMore(str(query_result[sf.queryLocator]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SOQL = 'SELECT id, Name, Department, Sales_Team__c FROM User'
    sync_user(SOQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make a list and append a DataFrame to it each time you go through the loop and have new results. Then at the end you can use `pandas.concat` to combine all the individual DataFrames into one.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat